# Merge shapefiles heatmap

Tags: qgis, shapefile, merge, heat-map

I have to merge few shapefiles into one and create a heat map out of it in QGIS. I'm a first user of the QGIS, I tried to do it there: vector-management tools-merge files into one, but it kept to make all the time just one output file out of the layer I wanted to merge, so I didn't actually merge them, but create something like copies out of them ...

I wish to have something like this:

[image]

(this pic is from my professor) but I have to have one for another group of tourists,

so I did this:

[image]

then I input a shapefile from the folder that consists all the shapeless that need to be merged, the I browsed the output file and named it Merge:

[image]

an this is what popped up, and I have no idea how to go on now.

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific please? Did you make sure all your shapefiles are in the same folder? Are they representing different features? If they represent the same features you're more likely looking for *Vector -> Geoprocessing -> Union*. Maybe edit your question and include a screenshot of your desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

> then I input a shape file from the folder that consists all the shapeless that need to be merged

That's a bit hard to understand but I think your problem is that you are selecting only one file to merge while you should select the folder:

[image]

Don't activate *Select by layers in the folder* if you want to merge **all** files in a folder anyway!